# Setting up default ForeignKey in django models

Tags: python, django

I need to set up default Foreign Key for a model at the model declaration stage (in models.py). I use the following code:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.pub_date)

def create_question():
    q=Question(question_text='default text', pub_date=datetime.now())
    q.save()
    return q.id

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, default=lambda: create_question())
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

This works fine, the Choice instance and associated Question instance are created... But saving of Choice instance leads to creation of two additional (useless) Question instances. It seems like that default-lambda is called several times during Choice instance saving. I don't need these additional Question instances. How to avoid their creation?

NOTE: In python-shell everything works well:

```
c=Choice(votes=5, choice_text='dim')
c.save()
```

creates one instance of Choice and one associated instance of Question. Only using admin save button leads to extra Question instances creation!

Comment: How did you save Choice instance? Could you show the code?

Comment: question = models.ForeignKey(Question, default=create_question())
works fine. Try to delete "lambda:" ?

Comment: Awesome! Everything works fine! Thanks!

Comment: @xuelang

`question = models.ForeignKey(Question, default=create_question())`

I don't think that this will work as desired: it will use same Question instance for all choices and it will also use `datetime.now()` for time of module import. Maybe you meant to propose `question = models.ForeignKey(Question, default=create_question)` (without `()` after `create_question`)